# Retrieve WatchCount From eBay API Based on Keyword Search

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm fairly new to the eBay API so trying to determine if this is even possible.

I'm trying to return a list of products based on a keyword, sorting by watch count and also displaying watch count.

I've tried the Finding API tutorial but from what I can tell you cannot display the watch count field.

I've also followed the Merchandising API tutorial here which allows you to get the 'Most Watched Items' by category.

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchandising/docs/HowTo/PHP_Merchandising/PHP_gMWI_GSI_gRCI_NV_XML/PHP_gmwi_gsi_grci_NV_XML.html

I tried to add a keywords section to the URL string but it didn't work.

Just wondering if anyone has had any experience doing this.